# PL/SQL insert using multiple selects and minus operator

Tags: oracle, plsql, oracle-apex

The following works:

```
INSERT INTO BASE_TABLE
(
    req, 
    desc,
    ver
)
    SELECT * FROM UPDATE_TABLE
minus
    SELECT req, desc, ver FROM BASE_TABLE;
```

However, this results in an error (just trying to insert one more field: 'key'):

```
INSERT INTO BASE_TABLE
(
    req, 
    desc,
    ver,
    key        
)
    SELECT * FROM UPDATE_TABLE
minus
    SELECT req, desc, ver FROM BASE_TABLE,
    SELECT CONCAT(req, ver) FROM UPDATE_TABLE;
```

Error:

**PL/SQL: ORA-00903: invalid table name**

Trying to insert rows into the BASE_TABLE by selecting everything from the UPDATE table that is NOT already in the BASE_TABLE. Just wanted to add the 'key' field.

The last SELECT seems to be out of place and causing this error.
Is the 'SELECT ... minus SELECT ...' equal to one statement, so the 3rd SELECT statement needs to be separated out? But how?

Comment: Take a look at `MERGE` - it is probably much better when you need to compare two tables for `INSERT`.

Comment: A few notes/questions: First, you will not be able to use `DESC` and `KEY` as column names (they are invalid object names because they are Oracle reserved words). In your actual data you probably have other names, but for testing `DESC` and `KEY` will not work. Then, in Oracle `concat()` is pretty limited (for example it takes only two arguments), you are better off using the `||` operator which does the same thing. Then, what data types are your `req` and `ver`? If they are not some character data type, Oracle will convert them implicitly, is that what you want?

Comment: Also, you concatenate req and ver with no separator; that is an odd kind of key. `req=1,ver=23` will have the same key as `req=12,ver=3` - is that what you need?

Comment: thanks mathguy, ill take a look at MERGE.
took out the real names, of course they came out to be reserved words :)
req is a unique value, should be good here.

Comment: I posted two solutions (they are quite different so I didn't show them as a single answer). One of them doesn't use MERGE, it just fixes your original attempt. (I think - I didn't test it.)

Answer (score 2):

To make it work as_is, your last "SELECT" should actually go to the outer query, like so:

```
INSERT INTO BASE_TABLE
(
    req, 
    desc,
    ver,
    key        
)
    SELECT req, desc, ver, CONCAT(req, ver)
    FROM 
    ( SELECT * FROM UPDATE_TABLE
      minus
      SELECT req, desc, ver FROM BASE_TABLE
    );
```

NOTE: This is a "lazy" solution, there should be no `SELECT *`, the column names should be spelled out in full. I just followed your lead... Right now, `UPDATE_TABLE` should have exactly the right number of columns, with the right names and in the right order, because you said your first query works (it wouldn't work otherwise). But if in the future you add a column to `UPDATE_TABLE`, the query with `SELECT *` will not work anymore, but the one with full column names will not be affected.

Comment: getting an error for this method:

PL/SQL: ORA-01789: query block has incorrect number of result columns

Comment: Sorry, that is right - let me fix it. (There still needs to be a subquery for the minus!)

Comment: my eye twitched when i saw 'minus' operator. first time working with pl/sql.

Comment: It's really SQL, and it's standard SQL. The `MINUS` operation is a basic set-theoretic operation and should exist in any relational database and language standard.

Comment: Haven't really ran into it. I showed this issue to another developer here and he hadn't seen it either. Maybe not common? Maybe you merge method is much clean way of approaching this kind of a problem?

Comment: In this case `merge` is cleaner (and possibly faster), but `minus` has its uses. The only set-theoretic operation that everyone uses all the time is `union` (and specifically, at least in Oracle, `union all` - so as not to eliminate duplicates).

Comment: Thank you. So far the code compiles and my process is not throwing any NULL errors. Now to dig into the DB and see if things actually got updated. I will def. keep your MERGE example close by for future reference.

Answer (score 0):

the two select based on mus shou contain tha same number and type of columns

try using

```
SELECT req, desc, ver FROM UPDATE_TABLE
 minus
SELECT req, desc, ver FROM BASE_TABLE
```

Answer (score 0):

**`MERGE` solution: an illustration**

**Documentation** here: https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/server.111/b28286/statements_9016.htm

I create two small tables for illustration. See my Comments to the original post: `desc` and `key` are reserved words so they can't be used as column names, I changed them accordingly. I used the `||` operator for concatenation and explicit conversions to character data type (`VARCHAR2`).

Create small test tables:

```
create table  base_table ( req, dscr, ver, ky ) as 
       select 1, 'alpha', 235, '1235' from dual union all
       select 2, 'beta' , 33 , '233'  from dual
;
select * from base_table;

       REQ DSCR         VER KY 
---------- ----- ---------- ----
         1 alpha        235 1235
         2 beta          33 233

create table update_table (req, dscr, ver) as
   select 1, 'alpha', 235 from dual union all
   select 5, 'rho'  , 444 from dual
;
select * from update_table;

       REQ DSCR         VER
---------- ----- ----------
         1 alpha        235
         5 rho          444
```

`MERGE` solution and result:

```
merge into base_table   b
    using  update_table u
    on     (b.req = u.req and b.dscr = u.dscr and b.ver = u.ver)
  when not matched then
    insert (   req,   dscr,   ver, ky                               )
    values ( u.req, u.dscr, u.ver, to_char(u.req) || to_char(u.ver) )
;

select * from base_table;

       REQ DSCR         VER KY 
---------- ----- ---------- ----
         1 alpha        235 1235
         2 beta          33 233 
         5 rho          444 5444
```